# Writing large data amounts to file quickly in Android

Tags: java, android, buffer

I have an issue in Java that I've been going at for about a week. I'm trying to find an efficient way to write around 90-120MB a second to external storage on Android without dropping data. In my test I have been getting 18-20MB/s which is the normal speed range for the external storage, however since the heap in Android per process is 140MB-256MB (I get 138MB max using largeHeap flag) it's impossible to make a large enough buffer to keep the data in tact using Java linked list or arrays (the data is generated at 90+MB/s). Is JNI a good option to create a large enough circular array or linked list to keep the data while the file write catches up? I saw another post where someone suggested making a service run in a separate process to get "extra" memory . I'm just worried about serialization slowing down the transfer of the generated data. I've deleted all of my code so far in frustration. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume you won't write that much amount of data forever. So maybe you consider AsyncTask ? It will take some more time but it should process all the data.

Answer (score 1):

To write 90-120 MB/s you need a device which supports this data rate.  Note: a typical HDD can't do this much.

You can add some extra buffering but this is not sustainable.  I suggest instead you find a way to write the same information in less data. e.g. by compressing the data.

BTW JNI won't make your device run faster, or give you more memory.

Comment: Thanks, I figured the buffer would run over after it's full since it can't literally catch up going at least 70MB/s slower than the data is given. I need to allocate a buffer at least 180MB in size which it seems only C will allow. I'll look into compression such as gzip or something for the data.

Comment: A 180 MB buffer will fill after 2 seconds.  I don't see why a) you need it as the OS should buffer uncommitted writes for you, b) cannot allocate a buffer of 180 MB in Java.  If you don't have this much heap you can use off heap/native/direct memory.  Or even better you can use a memory mapped file which doubles as a large off heap buffer and a way to write your data.

Comment: BTW how much free memory does you device have.  Obviously you can't allocate a useful buffer larger than this.

Comment: With the app running I still have around 320MB to spare (1GB of RAM total). As for the memory mapped file, I was researching this last night as a quicker, non-JNI way to achieve this. I didn't see that the memory map was off heap on any of the posts that mentioned this.

Comment: Memory mapped not only doesn't use much heap (just the wrappers for it) but doesn't use direct memory or swap either.  On an Ubuntu PC, I have used it to create an 8 TB file in memory with a 64-bit JVM with a very small heap (and no special command line parameters)

Comment: That's good to know. I'm researching reducing the data need and will check into memory maps as well. Since I need to write, do I have to create a file with zero bytes first?

Comment: On PCs, no.  You can just start using the file an mapping extents.  The behaviour of memory mapped files is OS dependant.